# Very high CPU usage on Linux server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, cpu-usage, linode

I have the following server:

- Ubuntu 14 LTS 64 bit
- Linode Hosting
- fail2ban enabled
- firewall enabled
- SSH root login diabled and only key access to server.

**Problem:**

When I run `htop`, it shows high CPU usage due to various commands like `whoami`, `grep "A"`, 'pwd' etc. Please help to stop this.

Here is the `htop` output:

[image]

Tree view of `htop`:

[image]

Comment: Could you please switch to tree view (press `t` or `F5` on your keyboard) so we can see where exactly these processes are launched?

Comment: Why are you running gnome on a VPS? o0 And everything is being run as root? You don't run things as root unless needed.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the machine? Sometimes a process goes rogue and hogs the CPU.

Comment: Yes, did reboot but it continue to eat cpu

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Understood but what is solution now ?

Comment: Unless you need to, stop gnome-terminal or better the whole X server or better install a server version (not desktop version) of Ubuntu.